# App crashes when opening image picker in marshmallow

Tags: android

I am using this way to open picker for image

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),      PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: you need to ask for the permission for Marshmellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask permission for read external storage

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 23;
```

**Ask for the permission before you call pick image**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }
```

Check your permission is granted or not

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {

            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this....

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
                            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);


          }
```

Tested.It will surely help you...